# call a external js file in to a nother js file

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, tinymce

I want to call external java script file in to the tinyMCE js and make all the functions available.

for eg -

I want to say to tinyMCE js that you have the Jquery moble in u and make all the functions available to tinyMCE.

.

This issue came since Im trying to implement (as i mentioned in my previous questions) jq mobile table system in to tinyMCE . 
1. issue is tinyMCE does not recognize  jq mobile. 
2. it seems it doesn't know that it has the jq mobile files in the iframe head already.
3. if we hard code a table to the editor it works fine . but when user want to insert a table in the run time it seems non of the jq mobile css get applied.

if some one know s a better way to implement this im open also.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a js file in your code using the folloing $.getScript

```
$.getScript("yourjs.js");
```

Comment: where should I include this ? on which part ? bit information regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: do I need to give the path ?